# SQL database, finding discrepancies

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table of amounts. The amounts are classified in 3 ways: semi-monthly, monthly, and quarterly.

- If Amount > 10000 = Semi-Monthly
- If Amount > 5000 = Monthly
- If Amount <= 5000 = Quarterly

The data in the Amounts table must match the above.

If there are any discrepancies I need to have it spit back out at me.

How do I go about writing this code?

Comment: You've tagged this for MySQL and Oracle.  Which database are you really using?  Does your table have an `Amount` column and a `Classification` column?

Comment: I meant to just tag Oracle. And yes it has both, Amount and Classification.

Comment: Are you trying to find this within a query or set up check constraints on the table?

Comment: I found out the discrepancies, but how do I get there to also be a column with what it should be.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could just check:

```
select t.*
from t
where ((amount > 10000 and classification <> 'Semi-Monthly') or
       (amount <= 10000 and amount > 5000 and classification <> 'Monthly') or
       (amount <= 5000 and classification <> 'Quarterly')
      );
```

This will return the discrepancies.

Comment: Thanks! Seems so obvious now.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bad idea to have both the amount and the classification in the same table. You have redundant data, which is why you are afraid now that the two columns may not match here and there.

Have a separate table for the classifications with the appropriate ranges:

```
table classification
====================

text         | range_start | range_end
-------------+-------------+----------
Semi-Monthly | 10001       | null
Monthly      | 5001        | 10000
Quarterly    | null        | 5000
```

and remove the classification from your table. Then whenever needed get the classification from a join:

```
select m.*, c.text as classification
from mytable m
join classification c on m.amount between coalesce(c.range_start, m.amount)
                                      and coalesce(c.range_end, m.amount);
```